# how to add two details together in database intertwined

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to send that data to firebase realtime databse but I don't know how to structure it that way exactly.

I tried this:

```
 myRef.child("user1").push().setValue("john").setValue("address");
```

but it does not work

I want this exactly:

```
user1
|
|-------name: john
|-------address: new yoek

user2
|
|-------name: mike
|-------address: michigan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
myRef.child("user1").child("name").setValue("john"); 
myRef.child("user1").child("address").setValue("new yoek"); 

myRef.child("user2").child("name").setValue("mike"); 
myRef.child("user2").child("address").setValue("michigan");
```

The `child()` creates an attribute and you need to use `setValue()` to give it a value.

Comment: yes but I want user1, user2 to be automatically generated... or any name or key

Comment: I want user1, user2, user3 etc. to be unique keys like `-KKm9iRSax-scGn7m3Lb`

Comment: Then u need to use `push()` instead of `child('user1')`

Comment: I know but I want name and address to be under the same key, how do I do that?

Comment: Do `String key = myRef.push().getKey()`, then do `myRef.child(key).child('name').....`

Comment: merci ya peter that's exactly what I wanted